# Error in proof of extreme value theorem (Protter and Morrey's book)

Tags: real-analysis

The bounded theorem has just been proved and thus is/may be used.

$f:[u,v]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and is continuous (so it is bounded)

We wish to show $\exists a,b\in[u,v]:f(a)=m, f(b)=M$ where $M=\sup(f(x))$ and $m=\inf(f(x))$

Let us prove $\exists b:f(b)=M$, we do this by contradiction. Suppose this is not true, that $M$ is not in the range of $f$ (so $M>f(x)\forall x\in I$), this means $M-f(x)>0$, so $F:x\mapsto\frac{1}{M-f(x)}$ is defined and continuous.

This means it is bounded.

Define $\bar M$ by $\bar M=\sup(F(x))$ then $\bar M>0$ and $\frac{1}{M-f(x)}\le \bar M$ **ERROR HERE**

Surely the authors mean $<\bar M$ because we are supposing that a bounded function that is continuous on a closed interval is less than its $\sup$, right?

The proof then goes on to show $f(x)\{\le|<\}M-\frac{1}{\bar M}$ which $<M$ contradicting that $M$ is the least upper bound/$\sup$

Have I spotted an error? If it isn't an error please help me learn enough so that I don't think it's an error (rather than just knowing it isn't).

Comment: `\mapsto` and `\overline{M}` are what you want, I think.

Comment: I've edited your post to use '\mapsto' and '\bar'. Although it is more standard to use $f:X\to Y$ to denote a function from $X$ to $Y$, and $x\mapsto x^2$ to define a function.

Comment: Also note that $\le$ follows from $<$, so it couldn't really be an *error*.

Comment: @AlexBecker I note at the end it doesn't change the conclusion but being right for the wrong reason isn't good! When I first hit Analysis I wanted to use "of course $\frac{1}{n}$ tends towards zero, I wouldn't want to live in a world where it didn't!" is not valid.

Comment: @AlecTeal There's a big difference between asserting a result and giving a perfectly correct proof in which one statement is weaker than it could be. But I agree it is best to use strict inequalities when they hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authors are only assuming that the function $f(x)$ in particular does not attain its maximum. Therefore they cannot assume that the other function $$F(x)=\frac{1}{M-f(x)}$$ does not attain *its* max. All they can say definitively is that it is less than or equal to its supremum, which must exist by continuity (and hence boundednesss). So no, it is not an error, but you are obviously a very close reader and that's a good thing!